# worked conservative question. Can someone double check?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you please check this question for me because my answer is different to my friends and they say it's wrong...

Given the equation: $G = (x^3 -3xy^2)\vec{i} +(y^3-3x^2y)\vec{j} +2\vec{k}$ is conservative, find the potential function for the fields that are conservative.

My answer
$f: \nabla f=F \\
fx=x^3-3xy^2 \\
fy=y^3-3x^2y \\
fz=z$

$\int(x^3-3xy^2)dx
=x^4/4-3x^2y^2/2 +h(y, z) \\
fy \text{ or } f'y= -3x^2 y +hy(y, z) \\
fy=y^3-3x^2y= -3x^2y+hy(y, z) \\
hy(y,z)=y^3$

$\int y^3 dy = y^4/4 +gz$
$fz=0$ because no $z$ term ^
$\int 0dz =c$
$F= x^4/4-3x^2y^2/2 +y^4/4+c$ <-potential function
my other friend solution was $F=x^4/4 -3x^2y^2/2 +z^2/2+y^4/4$.

Comment: I would suggest that you look at the vector field that you have provided and your statement about the quantity $ \nabla f = \vec{F}$ first something isn't right there.

Answer (score 3):

If we accept that the vector field $F = (x^3 -3xy^2)\vec{i} +(y^3-3x^2y)\vec{j} +2\vec{k}$ is conservative, so there is a function, say $f$ such that, $\nabla f=F$. So  $$f_x=x^3-3xy^2,~~f_y=y^3-3x^2y,~~f_z=z$$ Assume that $f_x=x^3-3xy^2$, so $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^4}4-\frac{3}2x^2y^2+h(y,z)$$ Then $f_y=-3x^2y+h_y(y,z)$ but $f_y=y^3-3x^2y$, so we get $$-3x^2y+h_y(y,z)=y^3-3x^2y\Longrightarrow h_y(y,z)=y^3\to h(y,z)=\frac{y^4}4+g(z)$$ Therefore, we have up to now: $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^4}4-\frac{3}2x^2y^2+\frac{y^4}4+g(z)$$ Now take a differentiation with respect to $z$, we have: $$f_z=g'(z)$$ but $f_z=z$, so $g'(z)=z$ and then $g(z)=\frac{z^2}2$. Hence $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^4}4-\frac{3}2x^2y^2+\frac{y^4}4+\frac{z^2}2$$

Comment: I think I type up the equation wrong for z component its z not 2 . So fz=z and don't you compare the y equation y^4/4+g(z) to fz? Im just confuse at that part

Comment: Wait what how... can you explain it again please because I know after you integral with respect to dy then you use that equation to fz but y^4/4 g(z) have no common term in fz=z .... I'm confuse there

Comment: Dont you do like this y^4/4 +g'(z)= z ?

Comment: Isnt if you g'(z)=z it become 1? :S

Comment: @Vince: Why $g'(x)=1$? Where did you get this result? Show me please. :-)

Comment: LOL that's what I'm saying... Im lost at that part because fromwhat I learn from class you integral dx then f'y using the integral equation then compare compare it to fy .I thought you have to equate the y^4/4+g(z) to fz  to compare it ...

Comment: $+1\,!\; \land \; \langle \ddot\smile \rangle$